# is for/while loop from python is a generator

Tags: python, generator, yield

In an interview , the interviewer asked me for some of generators being  used in Python. I know a generator is like a function which `yield` values instead of `return`.

so any one tell me is `for`/`while` loop is an example of generator.

Comment: A loop is something that can *iterate over* a generator, it is not itself a generator. Unless of course you're talking about the `(x for x in y)` generator syntax.

Comment: AFAIK, it is not. It is a loop structure. Mind however that there are other forms of generators.

Comment: May be this link helps you - http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html

Comment: Python provides a bunch of iterators in module [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html).

Comment: Thanks.. That all I was looking for.. now I got the clear idea about generators. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: **No**, but there are other forms of generators.

A **`for`/`while` loop is a *loop structure***: it does not emit values and thus is not a generator.

Nevertheless, there are **other ways to construct generators**.

You example with **`yield`** is for instance a generator:

```
def some_generator(xs):
    for x in xs:
        if x:
            yield x
```

But there are also ***generator expressions***, like:

```
(x for x in xs if x)
```

Furthermore in [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x) the **`range(..)`, `map(..)`, `filter(..)`** constructs are generators as well.

And of course you can make an ***iterable*** (by using an *iterable pattern*):

```
class some_generator(object):
    def __init__(self, xs):
        self.n = n
        self.idx = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        return self.next()

    def next(self):
        while self.num < len(self.xs) and not self.xs[self.num]:
            self.num += 1
        if self.num < len(self.xs):
            res = self.xs[self.num]
            self.num += 1
            return res
        else:
            raise StopIteration()
```

Comment: actually [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) is not (no longer?) a generator...

Comment: @hiroprotagonist: a `range(..)` constructs a `<type range>` object which has an `__iter__` function.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist: [this wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) says that "... and in Python 3 range() is a generator."

Comment: ['a Python generator is a kind of Python iterator, but of an especially powerful kind'](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/) as stated in PEP-0255. so: you are right! sorry! i assumed (which is wrong) that generators an be consumed once only, need to contain `yield` or be a generator expression.

Answer (score 5):

Neither `while` nor `for` are themselves generators or iterators. They are control constructs that perform iteration. Certainly, you can use `for` or `while` to iterate over the items yielded by a generator, and you can use `for` or `while` to perform iteration inside the code of a generator. But neither of those facts make `for` or `while` generators.

Answer (score 1):

The first line in [the python wiki for generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators):

> Generators functions allow you to declare a function that behaves like an iterator, i.e. **it can be used in a for loop.**

So in the context of your interview I'd believe they were looking for you to answer about the creation of an iterable.

The [wiki for a for loop](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop)

> In Python this is controlled instead by *generating* the appropriate sequence.

So you could get pedantic but generally, no, a for loop isn't a generator.

Answer (score 0):

for and while are loop structures, and you can use them to iterate over generators. You can take certain elements of a generator by converting it to a list.